# Getting the size of a cstring

Tags: c++

Is there a way to get the size of a null-terminated string?

Ex.

```
char* buffer = "an example";

unsigned int buffer_size; // I want to get the size of 'buffer'
```

Comment: Yes, there is, and it's trivial. You obviously haven't tried to google this.

Comment: CString is a type of string from the MFC, do you mean C-string? aka `char*` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that in C++11 a string literal has type `const char[]`, and the conversion to `char*` (i.e. pointer to non-`const`) is **illegal**. This said:

```
#include <cstring> // You will need this for strlen()
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char const* buffer = "an example";
    //   ^^^^^
    std::cout << std::strlen(buffer);
}
```

However, since you're writing C++ and not C (at least this is what the tag claims), you should use classes and algorithms from the C++ Standard Library:

```
#include <string> // You will need this for std::string
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string buffer = "an example";
    std::cout << buffer.length();
}
```

See a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4cvdpz%2443).

**NOTE:**

If there is an API you are using that requires a C-string, you can use the `c_str()` member function of an `std::string` object to retrieve a `char const*` pointer to a you can use the c_str() member function of an std::string object memory buffer containing the encapsulated C string. Just mind the fact that you cannot modify the contents of that buffer:

```
std::string s = "Hello World!";
char const* cstr = s.c_str();
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm actually writing a win app and I need to use cstrings, or do I?

Comment: @anon666: No, you don't need to. And you can use the `c_str()` member function of an `std::string` object to get a `char const*` pointer a memory buffer containing the encapsulated C string. Just mind the fact that you cannot modify the contents of that buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you brought up the const thing. It is perfectly fine to pass in a non-const `char*` to `strlen()`.

Comment: @BrianNeal: Yes, it is, but the assignment `char* buffer = "an example";` is not.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, the c_str() from the std lib. Okay, thanks to all for the help, espcially Andy :)

Comment: Ah, I missed the C++11 part.

Comment: _"Notice that in C++11 a string literal has type `const char[]`"_ No. It is `const char[N]` for some `N`. There is actually no such thing as "type `const char[]`", no matter what syntax inherited from C makes you believe!

Answer (score 4):

Try `strlen(buffer)` from `<cstring>`. It returns the length of the string you pass in.

Comment: Thanks @David. I forgot to include the include. :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to check for any functions from the standard clib